# How to find if two numbers vary a certain amount in python?

Tags: python, variables, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, difference

I would be searching a list of numbers that relate to each other in pairs and I need to find pairs that have a difference of 20 or more. Simply using > or < to find if one number is greater or less than another wont cut it because it needs to be less by at least 20.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

Just test if their difference is greater than 20 then. You can check it both ways, or just use the absolute function `abs(x - y) > 20`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am misunderstanding your question, but if I am not: say you have two numbers to compare `x,y`. You can check if they differ by 20 or more by checking `if x-y>20:`. If you don't know which is greater then you can use the absolute value. Absolute value will basically check if the value is negative and make it positive. For example say x=4, y=26. They differ by 20 or more so you want your if to return true, but x is less than y, so x-y will be negative (-22). To make it positive, use `abs(x-y)`. This way, your if statement will return true because it will make the -22 into 22.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Unsure what kind of data structure so I just used an array to create these pairs

(2) A quick solution is below

```
Arr = [(10,15),(15,40), (0,-20)]
for pair in Arr:
    diff = abs(pair[0] - pair[1])
    if(diff >= 20):
        #do whatever you want if difference between the two is more 20
        print(True)
    else:
        #do whatever you want if false
        print(False)
```

(3) you could create a function as well given a pair like below:

```
 def diff_of_pair_more_than_20(A,B):
    return True if abs(A-B) >= 20 else False
```